# How to disable RenderScript Logs in Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using RenderScript for some blur effects in my android application. The RenderScript is making the logcat fill up with logs about it, literally logging 2 to 4 logs every second which is making hard to finding logs that I actually want to see. Is there a way to filter out just the RenderScript logs?
P.S. I am already using "Show only Selected Application" filter in Logcat.

Comment: include the current application and exclude the RS, both with a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the package name of your application from the drop down menu where you choose the processes that will only show logs from that process.

Comment: I have but the render script logs are coming out from my application

Comment: @ChaitanyaSanoriya my comment already answers it, while you did not provide a single line of RS logcat output.